# ERROR: The method add(Integer) in the type ArrayList<Integer> is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Tags: java, arraylist

On the line `lengte.add("setLengteInM");` I get the error message:

```
The method add(Integer) in the type ArrayList<Integer> is not applicable for the arguments (String)
```

How do I solve this?

```
package ui;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

import domein.Marktkraam;

public class MarktkraamApplicatie {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Geef het aantal kramen op de rommelmarkt:");
        int aantalKramen = input.nextInt();
        
            while (aantalKramen <0)
            {
                    System.out.println("Geef het aantal kramen op de rommelmarkt:");
                    aantalKramen = input.nextInt();
            }
            
          int[] marktkraam = new int[aantalKramen];
          
          for (int i=0; i<marktkraam.length; i++)
          {
              ArrayList<String> naam = new ArrayList<String>();
              
              System.out.printf("Geef de naam van de eigenaar van kraam %d:", i+1);
              String setNaam=input.next();
              
              naam.add("setNaam");
              
             
              ArrayList<Integer> lengte = new ArrayList<>();
              System.out.printf("Geef de afmeting in meter van kraam %d:", i+1);
              int setLengteInM=input.nextInt();
              
            lengte.add("setLengteInM");

          }

    }
        
}
```

Comment: you have to remove quotes here `lengte.add("setLengteInM");` It should be `lengte.add(setLengteInM);`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add "setLengteInM" to your ArrayList but you can't do that because  "setLengteInM" is literally a text and your ArrayList type  is Int, so you have to replace with your variable name, something like this:

```
lengte.add(setLengteInM);
```